# Json parsing using Python loops

Tags: python, json, loops

I was trying to parse this JSON doc, which is the Reddit website http://www.reddit.com/.json
After loading it into a variable called `reddit_front` I try to go over it to count the number of `ups`.
I know the solution, which is the following:

```
def total_ups():
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    return sum(c["data"]["ups"] for c in j["data"]["children"])
```

However I would like to understand why my proposed loops didn't work:

```
def total_ups():
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    for c in j["data"]["children"]:
        return sum(c["data"]["ups"])
```

I have `'int' object is not iterable` error, isn't `i` here the iterator?

I also get an error when writing this:

```
    def total_ups():
        j=json.loads(reddit_front)
        for c in j["data"]["children"]:
            a = c["data"]["ups"]
            b += a
            return b
```

Why does it says `local variable 'b' referenced before assignment`? Doesn't `+=` exist in Python?

I think these two above questions come down to this:

```
def total_ups():
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    for c in j["data"]["children"]:
        return c["data"]["ups"]
```

Why do I get only one value and not all?

Thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: You're returning inside a `for` loop.  That means that the first time through the loop execution is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1) `sum` wants an interable

`sum` accepts as arguments something that reperesents multiple values; for example a list on which you want to compute the sum of the elements:

```
for c in j["data"]["children"]:
     return sum(c["data"]["ups"])
```

would is calling `sum` on a single value because you're already doing the iteration with the `for c in ...` statement. It also shows you don't understand how `return` works... see third point about it.

The expression `c["data"]["ups"] for c in j["data"]["children"]` is what Python calls *a generator expression* and can be used with functions that want to iterate on elements.

### 2) Python doesn't automatically initialize variables

In Python if you assign to a variable, using `a = 1` or even `a += 1` the variable is assumed to be a local variable of the function (unless you're at toplevel).
However all variables must be initialized before use and they're not automatically initialized like for example in PERL.

Thus before being able to use `b += x` inside some function you need to initialize `b` to 0 (if the values are numbers) or to `""` if they're strings and you want to concatenate them.

### 3) Return quits the current function and returns a value

Whatever is present after the first `return` is found during the execution of a function is ignored because `return` quits the function returning the value.
Python allows to define "generators" that can return multiple values but using `yield` and not `return`, for example:

```
def squares(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield x*x

print sum(squares(20))
```

will print 2470

Comment: That's what I wrote in the first part of my question, you are not answering it. I'm looking to understand why the other loops don't work.

Comment: @Bondifrench: yes, sorry. See edit. I somehow missed it on first reading and thought you didn't know how to get the computation right.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark you as giving the answer although @jh314 gave me what I find the clearest answer for the 2nd example. Many thanks for your explanations, and yes I don't fully understand some things and am often baffled by indentation problems in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that

```
c["data"]["ups"]
```

is an integer, so you cannot use `sum` on it.  (an `int` is not an iterable).  You need a list of numbers to sum:

```
def total_ups():
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    return sum(c['data']['ups'] for c in j['data']['children'])
```

For your second example, you need to initialize `b` to some value (most likely 0) before you can start adding stuff to it.  Also, you should fix indentation of the return statement so that you return the value of `b` only after the loop finishes.

```
def total_ups():
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    b = 0
    for c in j["data"]["children"]:
        a = c["data"]["ups"]
        b += a
    return b
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the clearest explanation for the second example.

Answer (score 0):

The first function you posted worked because inside the `sum` call on the last line, you are making a list (of ups) with list comprehension and then summing them up.

Moving onto the second one, you are calling sum on only the first `up` value, that is supposedly an integer. `sum` function expects an iterable (list, tuple, dict) as it's parameter but you passed in an integer here, hence the `'int' object is not iterable`.

```
def total_ups():
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    for c in j["data"]["children"]:
        return sum(c["data"]["ups"])  # it's like calling sum(86)
```

In the third one, you're calling `b += a`, which essentially equals to `b = b + a` but you haven't yet declared `b` but are adding it's value with `a` on the right side. Thus the `local variable 'b' referenced before assignment` error.

To answer the last question, you're getting just one value since the function returns at the first iteration of the loop and never gets the chance to go any further. Move the return call out of the loop.